# compiling java source using different source and bytecode version

Tags: java, compilation

Java compiler (sun's javac) allows user to specify source code compatibility level (with -source) as well as generated bytecode compatibility level (with -target).

Should there be concerns if I am to use different level for source and target (e.g. compiling 1.7 source to 1.5 bytecode, or the other way around)?

Answer (score 0):

> Should there be concerns if I am to use different level for source and target (e.g. compiling 1.7 source to 1.5 bytecode, or the other way around)?

Yes. Of course, new APIs developed for Java 7 will not exist in Java 1.5, so if you are using those APIs your application won't run

Answer (score 0):

The most common issue is that libraries available to Java 7 and not available in Java 5.0.

For this reason you need to compile using the same libraries as your target system to ensure you don't use a library which is not available.

BTW  The Sun/Oracle `javac` compiler only supports compiling 1.1 to 1.0 otherwise the source and target versions have to be the same.

Comment: I take it by library you mean the API? As for your side note, thanks it leads me to I finding out that this kind of cross compilation only works upwards (lower source version to higher bytecode version) from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

Comment: @bluearth You can't compile a Java 5.0 source for anything but Java 5.0.  It will run on a Java 7 JVM, but it will still be Java 5.0 source.

Answer (score 0):

> compiling 1.7 source to 1.5 bytecode ...

If you mean that you are trying to compile using `javac -source 1.7 -target 1.5` then I'm afraid that won't work.  Enabling the new Java 1.7 language features requires the target to be 1.7.  This is a common pattern.  When new language features are added, the classfile version number is typically increased, and you typically need to compile to the corresponding target version (or higher).

`javac -source 1.5 -target 1.7` `javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5` would work, though in the latter case you may get a compiler warning if you don't compile against the Java 1.5 edition of the 'rt.jar' file.